# Spring data JPA not returning record while same exists in table

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity Student which has a column name username. I am trying to fetch a student in studentRepository with below method:

```
@Query("select x from Student x where x.userName=:userName")
Student findStudentByUserName(@Param("userName")String  userName)
```

While the record exists in table, this method is returning null. To cross verify, I executed the query prepared by hiberante that is printed in logs. That returned the intended record as expected.

Can someone help me to understand the issue?
Thanks

Edit: as asked in comments, sharing repository class

```
package com.pinelabs.pineklik.repository.lead;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
    
    @Query("select x from Student x where x.userName=:userName")
    Student findStudentByUserName(@Param("userName")String  userName);

}
```

Forgot to mention that this works fine in all enviroment but dev/local machine.

Solution: My bad. Extremely ridiculous of me to have pointed to local db instead of test db which was causing the issue.

Comment: are you using JPA? can you please post your repository class?

Comment: Below are the import statments if this helps:

package com.pinelabs.pineklik.repository.student;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

Comment: I want to see how you have declared your repository class. you can omit the methods if you want.

Comment: Updated the question with this. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@Query` and try this. This is assuming that there is a String field `userName` in `Student` entity class.

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
    
    
    Student findByUserName(String userName);

}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that same code is working fine in rest of the environments but dev/local machine. :(

Comment: any error messages?

Comment: no, just the query does not return any data, and I had a check to throw error if no data is returned. That's the implementation.
Just for the sake, I clean buit my project. No luck

Comment: please show me your entity class